# Quickie: where's the ForeignKeyAttribute in EF5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I can't find this attribute in EF5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx

Can someone tell me where it went? Is it obsolete and replaced by another class from DataAnnotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i just had to change target framework from 4 to 4.5.